# Have set up Django on Ubuntu 16.04 and now can't login

Tags: django, ubuntu

I have set up a simple Django project with MySQL on Ubuntu 16.04 using wsgi

Have created a superuser as per the docs, and have verified that the user exists in the auth_user table, and that the status is superuser. Everything looks great!

However, I can't login via the admin url - I just get a 500 server error and don't know of a way to check what could possibly be going wrong.

However, if I run the site with the Django server (python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000), I can login with no problem.

It doesnt make a difference whether DEBUG is set to True or False.

I hope someone who's had the same type of issue can help!

Many thanks.

UPDATE

screenshot of 500 error when trying to login, DEBUG set to True

[image]

Comment: did u have problem in wsgi add the script

Comment: check for logs, console, also have you migrated your DB correctly?

Comment: If you set DEBUG to True, you will get a more detailed error message. Could you post that here?

Comment: Hi many thanks for getting back. There is no problem with the wsgi script in that the front end works fine - I don't think that's the issue. Have also tested it on another site where I logged in using SQLlite. I believe the DB has been migrated ok -- having checked the tables in the MySQL console they are all there and I have inspected the auth_user table - it's fine, and as I say I can login fine when using the django server. Even if I set DEBUG to True, all I get is a 500 error - nothing more, see attached. I'm sorry I don't have more info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you gave permission to www-data user for apache server ? If not, then try  following commands

```
sudo adduser $USER www-data 
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/venv/project_name
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/venv/project_name/db.sqlite3
```

Comment: Many thanks for this - is this for sqllite (which I'm not using in production) or will it work for mysql? Also, I am trying to get Logging to work so I can send the appropriate emails to the site admin but not having used it before, am struggling with that at the moment!

Comment: Hi I have done
sudo adduser $USER www-data
My test project and the virtualenvironment live in separate locations (under the same user) so I have tried
sudo chown www-data:www-data /home/.../virtualenvs/project_env
sudo chown www-data:www-data /home/.../djangoprojects/project_name
Not sure what to do as I'm using MySQL..

Comment: Hi again, I can login now ! I guess it must have been running the last set of commands - many thanks for that! I didnt need to add anything for mysql.

Comment: I missed it that you are using MySql, making www-data the owner of project would have solved the problem :)